# Tangents from a point to two given circles that form equal angles with a line passing through that point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, tangent-line, geometric-construction

**Line $p$ and circles $k$ and $l$ are given. Construct  point $T$ on line $p$ such that  tangents to circles $k$ and $l$ from  point $T$ form equal angles with line $p$. How many solutions are there?**

[image]

I don't know why but I just drew a line $t$ parallel to $p$ passing through the center of circle $l$. Then I found the perpendicular bisector of $IJ$ where $I=t\cap l$ and $J=t \cap k$. I thought the interesction of that perpendicular bisector with the line $p$ would be point $T$. But apparently it's not even tho it's close. Any hints would be appreciated.

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain which angles are supposed to be equal ?

Comment: @Sathvik I added a pic to my original post that explains what I'm trying to achieve since I can't post it in this comment

Comment: Reflect $k$ about $p$ to $k'$ and construct a tangent common to $l$ and $k'$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I did it sir! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As shown in figure, mirror circle d about the line to get circle d'. Draw common tangent i of circles d' and c, it intersect the line at P. Draw a tangent j from P on circle d. Tangents i and j are solutions. Now draw another common tangent k passing point S on circle c, it intersect the line at T. Draw tangent l from T on the circle d passing point U. Tangent l and TS are another solution. Could you find the reason?

Comment: Yes, I can. If tangent $i$ touches circles $d'$ and $c$ at points $S_1$ and $S_2$,respectively, then $\angle (p, PS_1)=\angle(p, PS_2)$ because they are vertical angles. Now if we reflect $PS_1$ about $p$ we get a ray $PS_1'$ that will be tangential to the original circle $d$ (because its just "undoing" the reflection part, so if a line is tangential to a circle, its reflection about some line will be tangential to the reflection of the circle about that same line) .

Comment: And since $\angle(p,PS_1)=\angle (p,PS_1')$ and $\angle (p, PS_1)=\angle(p, PS_2)$, we finally get that $\angle (p,PS_1')=\angle(p, PS_2)$, hence $P$ is the required point.Thank you sir, I really struggled with this problem!!!